# Show that the closure of $\Bbb Q\cup\{i\}$ is a field

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let K be the closure of $\Bbb Q\cup\{i\}$, that is, $K$ is the set of all numbers that can be obtained by (repeatedly) adding and multiplying rational numbers and $i$, where is the complex square root of -$1$. Show that $K$ is a field.

Comment: How about you start by listing the axioms of a field?  This should be quite straightforward after that, and if you get stuck at any axiom you can edit you question for more explanation.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that : )

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Show that $K=\{\,a+ib\mid a,b\in\mathbb Q\,\}$ and observe that $(a+bi)(a-bi)\in\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Thank you! This is very helpful!

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106330/field-extension-obtained-by-adjoining-a-cubic-root-to-the-rationals.