# what's the inverse of $1 + \alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a root of $p(x) = x^3 + 9x + 6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

**Show that $p(x) = x^3 + 9x + 6$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$. Let $\alpha$ be a root of $p(x)$. Find the inverse of $1 + \alpha$ in $\mathbb Q[x]$.**

So as far as the irreducibility  is conccerned we can use the Einseinstein criterion (p=3).
But how can we find the inverse of $1 + \alpha$?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you want the inverse of $1+\alpha$ in ${\bf Q}(\alpha)$, not in ${\bf Q}[x]$.

Divide $p(x)$ by $1+x$; $$p(x)=(1+x)q(x)+r$$ Then substitute $x=\alpha$, and maneuver a bit.

Comment: This is just the Extended Euclidean algorithm - see my answer.

Comment: I'd say it's just the Division Theorem.

Comment: No, it's the special case of the Extended Euclidean Algorithm when it terminates in a *single step*, i.e. when it requires just one application of the Division Algorithm. To invert elements of *higher* degree generally requires *multiple* applications of the Division Algorithm i.e. the full Extended Euclidean Algorithm. Said structurally it amounts to the fact that Euclidean domains are Bezout domains.

Comment: @Bill, you are making a distinction between using the Division Theorem and using the Division Theorem just once? A distinction without a difference, I think.

Comment: My point is that students reading only your answer likely will have no idea how to invert other polynomials (of higher degree) by using the *extended Euclidean algorithm* (of which the above is a special (linear) case, i.e. the case when the algorithm terminates in a single step).  And, btw, there are many proofs that "use the division algorihm more than once" that have nothing to do with the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score -1):

As for integers, [the extended Euclidean algorithm computes modular inverses,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2959891/242) and terminates in one step, since here $\rm\,x+1\,$ has degree $1,\,$ i.e.  $\rm\, a\,p + b\,(1\!+\!x) = 1\,$ $\rm\Rightarrow\, (1\!+\!x)^{-1} = b\,$ in $\rm\,\Bbb Q[x]/(p).$

---

**Or** $ $  let $\,X=x\!+\!1\,$ and $\, p(x) = p(X\!-\!1) =  g(X)\:\!X-c,\ $
therefore  $\bmod p(x)\!:\ \ g(X)\:\!X^{\phantom{|^|}}\!\!\!\equiv c\,\Rightarrow\, X^{-1}\equiv g(X)/c\,\ $ (remark: this can be [viewed as](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100201/242) **rationalizing the denominator** of $\,\frac{1}X\,$ using the norm $\,c\,$ as a "simpler multiple" of $X$)