# Question about Subrings and integraly closed

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, integral-extensions

The following is a proposition from abstract algebra. The book gives this as a proposition and asks the reader to do it as an exercise. It seems it should be easy. (Assuming every ring has a $1$.)

> Let $R$ be a subring of $S$. If $S \setminus R$ is closed under multiplication, then $R$ is integrally closed in $S$.

I went by contradiction. Let $s$ be in $R \setminus S$. Then, we get that
$$
s^n+a_1s^{n-1} + \cdots + sa_{n-1}+a_{n}=0
$$
for some $n$ and the $a$'s are in $R$. Now I am thinking this
$$
s^n=(-1)(a_1s^{n-1} + \cdots + sa_{n-1}+a_{n})
$$
Now multiply both sides by $s$ again to get
$$
ss^n=(-s)(a_1s^{n-1} + \cdots + sa_{n-1}+a_{n})
$$
Now by closure, $ss^n$ is in $S \setminus R$ which means the rest $a_1s^{n-1} + \cdots + sa_{n-1}+a_{n}$ is in $S \setminus R$ which means the $a_i$'s are in it, which is a contradiction.
Does this look correct?

---

**Edit** (not by OP): The above is also Exercise 7 from Chapter 5 of Atiyah and Macdonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*.

Comment: Why to denote by $\;s\;$ an element in $\;R\setminus S\;$ ? To confuse? Anyway, if $\;R\subset S\;$ , then it **must** be $\;s\in S\setminus R\;$ . Finally, at the end you say "...which is a contradiction"? To **what** ? Where did you clearly state what is the assumption you make? I think I know what you meant, yet you must explicitly state this.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se]. Please don't edit out your question after you have received an answer/a hint, the purpose of the site is to have the questions and answers as resources for others having the same or a sufficiently similar problem in the future. Editing the question out to say thanks defeats that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ Choose $\,n\,$ minimal. Then $\ s f(s) = s (s^{n-1}+ r_{n-1} s^{n-2} + \cdots + r_1)\, =\, -r_0.\,$ But $\,f(s)\not\in R\,$ by minimality of $\,n\,$ so $\,s,f(s)\in S\backslash R \,\Rightarrow\, sf(s) = -r_0\in S\backslash R ,\,$ contradiction.

Comment: The base case $\,n = 1\,$ is trivial: $\ s+r_0 = 0\,\Rightarrow\, s = -r_0\in R.\,$

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100201/242).