# Divide a number by a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, divisibility, recreational-mathematics

Is it possible to divide a single number by a complex number? What would be the result?

For example:

$\frac{5}{2+3j}$

What would this equal?

Or is this an illegal operation?

Comment: Hint: multiply by $\frac{2-3j}{2-3j}$.

Comment: @user722227 thanks homie i gotchu now

Comment: [Rationalize the denominator](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100201/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque thx but i already got it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint will lead you to the right answer which I'm sure you can carry out this computation. Note that since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field (just like $\mathbb{R}$), you can divide by any non-zero element (which is just multiplication by the inverse)