# Let $D$ be an integrity domain and $F$ a subfield of $D$.

Tags: field-theory

If $d$ ∈ $D - \{0\}$ is such that there exists a nonzero polynomial $f(x) ∈ F[x]$ such that $f(d) = 0$, show that there exists $d^{−1} ∈ D$.

I know that $D ⊃ F$, and $F$ is a field with respect to the restrictions of the operations of $D$, but I don't know how to follow the proof..

Comment: Write down explicitly the polynomial, then, note that the constant term is equal to $d$ times an element in $D$. Finally, consider the cases: constant term zero/non-zero.

Comment: See also [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100201/242) for motivation and generalizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=a_nx^n+\ldots+a_1x+a_0$ (where all $a_i$'s are from $F$) be such that $f(d)=0$, and $f$ is the *smallest degree* polynomial from $F[x]$ with that property. This means that:

$$a_nd^n+\ldots+a_1d+a_0=0$$

Now:

- If $a_0=0$, this means that already $(a_nd^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1)d=0$, but as $d\ne 0$ and $D$ is an integral domain, we conclude $a_nd^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1=0$, i.e. there is a *smaller* degree polynomial $g(x)=a_nx^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1$ such that $g(d)=0$ - a contradiction.
- If $a_0\ne 0$, then there is $a_0^{-1}\in F$, so you can now calculate that:

$$-a_0^{-1}(a_nd^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1)d=1$$

which means $d$ is invertible and $d^{-1}=-a_0^{-1}(a_nd^{n-1}+\ldots+a_1)$.