# $| \{a \in \mathbb{Z}_{24} : a^{1001} = [5]\} |=?$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We want to find the number of items of the set $\{a \in \mathbb{Z}_{24} : a^{1001} = [5]\} $

Case: $\gcd(a,24)=1$

Using

- Euler's Theorem (if $(\gcd(a,n))=1 \Rightarrow a^{\phi(n)}\equiv1\bmod n$)
- $\phi(24)=\phi(2^3)\cdot\phi(3)=4\cdot2=8$
- $1001=8\cdot125+1$

we get,

$$a^{1001}=a^{8\cdot125}\cdot a \equiv a\bmod24 \equiv 5\bmod 24\Leftrightarrow a \equiv 5 \bmod24.$$

Case: $\gcd(a,24)\neq 1$

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Second case can't work:   if $d\mid a\;$ and $\;d\mid 24\;$ and $\;24\mid a^{1001}-5$, then $d\mid 5,$ so $\;d\mid1$

Comment: $a^{1001}\!= 5\Rightarrow a\mid 5\,$  so $\,5$ unit $\Rightarrow a\,$ unit, by divisors of units are units (cf. 2nd dupe). The rest (which you've done) is a special case of [mod order reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2033681/242) using Euler's Theorem, see the first dupe.  Recall unit means invertible, which here are the elements coprime to $24.\ \ $

Comment: More generally a root $\,r\,$ of a polynomial $\,f(x)\,$ divides its constant coef $\,f(0),\,$ so $\,f(0)\,$ unit $\Rightarrow r\,$ unit, e.g. see [inversion via norms](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/100201/242), e.g. rationalizing denominators, e.g. in OP  $$\dfrac{1}{\color{#c00}a} \,=\, \dfrac{a^{1000}}{a^{1001}}\,=\,\dfrac{a^{1000}}{\color{#0a0}5}\qquad$$
shows how  we can view $\,\color{#0a0}5\,$ invertible $\,\Rightarrow \color{#c00}a\,$ invertible as "rationalizing" the denominator of $\large \,\frac1{\color{#c00}a}\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

The comment under the question already provides an answer, but let me give another.

Notice that $\gcd(5, 24) = 1$, so $5$ has multiplicative inverse modulo $24$.

On the other hand, any $a$ such that $\gcd(a, 24) \neq 1$ is not invertible, so any of its powers cannot be invertible as well. Therefore no power of $a$ can give you $5$ modulo $24$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing).