# $x\in R$ is a unit iff $(x+RadR)$ is a unit in $R/RadR$

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Prove that the element $x\in R$ is a unit iff $(x+RadR)$ is a unit in $R/RadR$. ($RadR$ is Jacobson radical of $R$)

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\hat x$ is invertible in $R/J(R)$ implies $\hat x\hat y=\hat 1$ for some $y\in R$, that is, $1-xy\in J(R)$, so $1-(1-xy)=xy$ is invertible (in $R$) and therefore $x$ is invertible.

Comment: Can you explain why $xy$ is invertible in $R$ implies $x$ is invertible?

Comment: Okay. Thank you very much.

Comment: This post makes your hint more precise http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99949/if-xy-is-a-unit-are-x-and-y-units?rq=1